# Multi-line button labels

Tags: basic4android

Is there an easy way to have two lines of button.text where you specify each line individually?  Also, there seem to be large margins on the buttons so the text font needs to be quite small to fit.  Is there a way to allow the text to use more of the button area?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do a two-line text implementation is:

```
Dim t1,t2 As String
t1="This is line one"
t2="This is line two"
...
MyButton.Text = t1 & CRLF & t2
```

The CRLF performs a Carriage Return and Line feed thus splitting the text up

I can't help with the padding issue though. Have you tried changing the font size?

```
MyButton.TextSize=9
```

Comment: An example of setting the padding using the Reflection library is available here [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/11286-edittext-height.html#post63103)

Comment: I'm rewriting a VB .net program I wrote that emulates an operator terminal used on some old (1980's) industrial equipment.  There is serial data that is received that updates the text on the buttons.  The system I'm interfacing with sends two lines for each button.  In VB, I just did the & thing for the two lines and set the font so it always worked out that the text ended up on two lines.  Now that I'm writing it again, I figured it would be easier to use the two separate lines themselves.  This should help.  Thank you.